# Reading data from database that was inserted by another Spring Boot JPA project

Tags: java, database, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I have two projects

1. ProjectA --> 'Spring Boot JPA based Java` project
2. ProjectB --> General 'Java' project

My `Database` is `MySQL Server`

My `ProjectA` is a web project so from a webpage I was able to get a lot of data inserted into multiple tables without any `insert` queries. This is because it's a `JPA` project and it was super easy.

Now I want to access the same data from the same database in a few `Java` classes in my `ProjectB`. I don't want to convert this into a `Spring Boot` project and make it more complex just to read data from two tables.

On the other hand I really don't want to use `JDBC Connectors` and process `ResultSet` etc. I like the way how `annotations` were used in `Spring Boot JPA project` to write and read data from the database.

What options do I have here?

Answer (score 1):

You can use spring's `JDBCTemplate` or `HibernateTemplate` to minimize your code.

Comment: Even if I use Spring's `JDBC Template` I still have to convert my `ProjectB` to a `Spring` based project and everytime I have to start it as a `Spring Boot` application using the `embedded Tomcat` right?